# How do I troubleshoot minute-long hangs during boot?

Tags: boot, xubuntu

I have an issue with a fairly old laptop hanging during boot. It started a while back, when I upgraded to 21.04, or maybe 21.10. To try gather info about the issue, I set verbose boot without splash and the issue went away without explanation, at least until 22.04 came out. With verbose boot, the last message before a hang was about USB, with nothing plugged in, I think that could only be the card reader. Since then, I've reloaded my system and not set it back to verbose, splash-less boot.

What's the best way to troubleshoot this issue?

Xubuntu 22.04 on an Acer travelmate 5735 CPU is core 2 duo t6670.

Comment: Start with `systemd-analyze blame`.

Comment: Another useful is `systemd-analyze critical-chain`

Comment: Logs can be helpful, too.

Comment: `systemd-analyze blame` gave me 102 entries, with only 7 above 1s one at 7s, the sum probably equals about boot up time minus 60s. and `systemd-analyze critical-chain` gives me similarly little to work with.  Assume my troubleshooting skills are negligible (because so often, my stuff works) but assume also that I've blundered my way through Ubuntu well enough over the years to command-line host WordPress, or NextCloud (snap or full LAMP stack).  @user535733, which logs... more input, Stephanie.

Comment: Your `blame` output "*one at 7s*" seems to disagree with "*minute-long hangs during boot*." That's the list of what the system was doing, including during apparent hangs. Are you satisfied? Or do you feel that more troubleshooting is necessary?

Comment: Hey up everyone! The sum of my blame output is 44s. I timed up to display manager yesterday, 2m40s, getting longer. Immediately after, a reboot took under 30s, and that's the first time the device rebooted any quicker than a cold start. Freeze happens soon as BIOS screen completed. There's a flicker of the drive LED, a long pause, then boots up quickly soon as LED lights again. Just such a weird one... Things I may try, a different SSD, or I could move boot and grub to an SD card. Maybe see what happens with another distro... I'll report my findings.